# Sweble wikipedia parser

Tags: xml-parsing, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am currently working on one project which involves parsing of wikiText of whole Wikipedia. Do anybody know about Sweble wikipedia parser? I found this parser on [1]: http://sweble.org
Can you guys comment on this parser if you have used it before or suggest some other parser?

Thanks in advance.